# how to present UIViewController from SKScene

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, skscene

Usaly when you present a viewController from another viewController you do:

```
let vc : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewController") as UIViewController;
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

I want to present a viewController from a SKScene. I haven't found any way of doing that.
This question might be a duplicate, but i have just found answers in objective C that doesn't make sense to me

Comment: pretty sure there are also swift-specific questions (some even may have answers) because "how to access view controller from scene", "how to present view controller from scene" and similar are very frequently asked questions

Answer (score 9):

Try the following in your scene class:

```
var currentViewController:UIViewController=UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow.rootViewController!

currentViewController.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This Works! Thank You!